# How do I ensure proper routing with logstash when I update a parent/child relationship document?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a parent/child relationship setup in elastic search. When I try to update the parent it sometimes works and sometimes not. I believe I've narrowed it down to getting a missing document error because I can't figure out how to specify routing using logstash. (Parent/Child relationships must route to the same shard). I thought elasticsearch would do this automatically given that I have setup the routing path in the mappings but it only seems to work when I specify the routing paramater in the REST API URL. But, logstash doesn't seem to have a way to add that when updating. I'm using the logstash elastic-search output plugin with http protocol.

To add to my confusion it seems elasticsearch 1.5 is deprecating the "path" property in mappings.

Is there any way to ensure proper routing with parent/child updates using logstash?